# How to show/hide password field in Gigya

Tags: javascript, html, css, passwords, gigya

I created password field with 'eye' on the right side by using html, js and css outside Gigya. The text in the password field will hide/show by clicking the eye.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aruOH.png)

I am trying to do the same in Gigya. However, the problem comes -
1. I'll be unable to use UI Builder again if I edit the html file.
2. Javascript parameter in RaaS of Gigya does not allow me the add js EXCEPT adding the code the defined functions.

My question is - how do I do that in Gigya?

If I want to use check box as shown [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QmhN.png) instead of 'eye', how does Gigya handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add any custom css classes to the CSS Styles tab of the UI Builder, it is near the bottom of the left-hand list of the screens in the UI Builder (near the JavaScript Parameters) and then you can add the class to the password fields using the CSS Classes field of the fields Property window (right-hand side of the UI Builder when the field is selected).

You can add your custom JS inside the [onAfterScreenLoad](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/accounts.showScreenSet+JS#accounts.showScreenSetJS-Events) event of the screen, using the JavaScript editor, and it will run immediately after the screen is drawn. - Alternatively, you can host all the custom JS on the page locally in a function and then just add the onAfterScreenLoad param inside the showScreenSet call, i.e.,

```
gigya.accounts.showScreenSet({
   "screenSet": "Default-RegistrationLogin",
   "onAfterScreenLoad": myFunctionName
});
```

Any HTML changes will be a little more difficult, but you may be able to do it using that same event with JQuery or something. I can look into it and see if there is any other way and update in a couple days.

**Nov 12th, Updated with a working example:**

Here is a functioning example, I only did it for the login screen, it will need additional work to fully support the registration screen also:

```
gigya.accounts.showScreenSet({
    "screenSet": "Default-RegistrationLogin",
    "onAfterScreenLoad": function() {
        var fieldToChange = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];
        var newPwDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newPwDiv.id = 'passSwitch';
        newPwDiv.innerHTML = "-O-"; // change this out with your image
        newPwDiv.setAttribute('style', 'float: right !important; color: red !important; z-index: 9999999999999999999 !important; display: block !important; position: absolute; margin: -41 0 0 334; cursor: pointer !important; text-align: center;');

        // add eventListener
        newPwDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
            var currentValue = fieldToChange.type;
            if (currentValue === 'password') {
                fieldToChange.type = "text";
            } else {
                fieldToChange.type = "password"
            }
        });
        // attach to password field
        fieldToChange.parentElement.appendChild(newPwDiv);
    }
});
```

[image: Example]

**November 14th, Updated with additional Info**

To do this via the UI Builder only, you can add any relevant CSS to the CSS Styles tab of the UI Builder:

[image]

You can then add your JavaScript to the JavaScript Parameters tab:

[image]

[Link to demo](https://gigyademo.com/bin/password-toggle-demo/) Updated

If you still are having issues, I suggest opening a Support ticket via your Gigya Console and we can look into your specific use-case.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Levi!

Comment: The following is the one (CSS/HTML/JS) that I try to add to Gigya, and I think I am still missing something -

Comment: <!-- CSS -->
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
 <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>

 <style>
   .field-eye-icon {
  float: right;
  margin-left: -25px;
  margin-top: -25px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
   }

   .eye-container{
  padding-top:50px;
  margin: auto;
   }
 </style>

Comment: <!-- HTML -->
 <div class="eye-container">
   <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <input id="password-field" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" value="show/hide">
    <span toggle="#password-field" class="fa fa-fw fa-eye-slash field-eye-icon toggle-password"></span>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>

Comment: <!-- js -->
 <script src='https://bowercdn.net/c/jquery-2.2.2/dist/jquery.min.js'></script>
 <script>
  $(".toggle-password").click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
    var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
    if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
   input.attr("type", "text");
    } else {
   input.attr("type", "password");
    }
  });
 </script>

Comment: 'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'
  'maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css' 
'bowercdn.net/c/jquery-2.2.2/dist/jquery.min.js'

Comment: Well, first, you can not change out the Gigya password field with a new one, as Gigya uses specific data attributes to process the forms. If you want to create a screen from scratch, you can check out the [Markup Reference](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Markup+Extensions) which you will need to use in order to maintain functionality.

Comment: I have added a [public demo here](https://demo.gigya.com/bin/password-toggle-demo/), if you want to check it out. I did not edit the screen-set at all or add anything to the UI Builder or global Conf object. This is strictly using JavaScript. I used a static image for the 'eye', though it should be simple enough to use the font instead and just attach the function that changes the eye with the eye-slash into the same function that is controlling the field 'type'.

Comment: I have the following code and it works inside Gigya RaaS by click on Preview. However, it does not work outside the Gigya RaaS, i.e. using the url. I notice the function "onFieldChanged: function(event)" gets call inside Gigya RaaS, but this function does not get call by using the url. Any thought?

Comment: // show/hide password
            var fieldToChange = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];
            var newPwDiv = document.createElement('div');
            newPwDiv.id = 'passSwitch';
            newPwDiv.innerHTML = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css\"> <i class=\"fa fa-eye-slash\"></i>";

Comment: newPwDiv.setAttribute('style', 'float: right !important; color: red !important; z-index: 2 !important; display: block !important; margin: -41 0 0 334; cursor: pointer !important; text-align: center; margin-left: -25px; margin-top: -25px; position: relative;');

            // add eventListener
            newPwDiv.addEventListener("click", function() {
                var currentValue = fieldToChange.type;
                if (currentValue === 'password') {

Comment: newPwDiv.innerHTML = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css\"> <i class=\"fa fa-eye\"></i>";
                    fieldToChange.type = "text";
                } else {
                    newPwDiv.innerHTML = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css\"> <i class=\"fa fa-eye-slash\"></i>";
                    fieldToChange.type = "password";
                }

Comment: });
            // attach to password field
            fieldToChange.parentElement.appendChild(newPwDiv);
    },

    // Called when a field is changed in a managed form.
    onFieldChanged: function(event) {
    console.log("onFieldChanged: function(event)");
    },

Comment: It's difficult for me to follow exactly what you are doing with these code snippets. I added another demo to the [previous page](https://demo.gigya.com/bin/password-toggle-demo/) where I am hosting the css and the JS inside the UI Builder. I am going to edit the original answer with some additional images of where to place the code within the UI Builder.

Comment: Thanks for the Nov. 14 updates, Levi! Have you tried it outside RaaS, i.e. create an url and run it by using url. It fails to add the 'eye' to the field in my case.

Comment: I don't know what you mean 'outside of RaaS' or 'create a URL'. Can you be more specific? Screen-sets need to be hosted on a page or in an app's webview. Can you clarify?

Comment: Instead of access to the screen-sets, say ABC via gigya console, for example https://console.gigya.com/site/partners/Settings.aspx#/xxx/dashboard;
You host your own URL directly access to the screen-sets ABC, for example http://dev.mycompany.com/html/gigya-app/.
What I mean is that the 'eye' shows up and show/hide password by clicking at the 'eye' in the gigya console environment, i.e. https://console.gigya.com/site/partners/Settings.aspx#/xxx/dashboard. 
However, the 'eye' does not show, i.e. http://dev.xxxxx.com/html/gigya-app/.
Have you encountered such problem?

Comment: Ok, so that is normal use. You are using the screens on your site that are hosted in the UI Builder.

Comment: The only think I can think of is that the resources aren't available on your page. Be sure to check that, for instance, if your site is running on SSLthat all the references in your code do not reference a non-SSL verison of any resources, or they won't load on the page; Be sure that the resources are available on your site.
Assuming it is a normal html/php/javascript website, if you are using a node app, it may be a bit different.there is a 3rd party [Node SDK](https://developers.gigya.com/display/GD/Third+Party+SDKs) for use with RaaS

Comment: Check the dev console of your browser and ensure that nothing is being blocked or refusing to load.

Comment: I thought about that, however, it seems not the case. For example in your Nov. 14 sample code, instead of using resource png, I just simply use 'passowordEyeDiv.innerHTML = "--0--";' There is no resource issue. What I noticed is that "onFieldChanged: function(event)" gets call inside Gigya RaaS, but this function does not get call by using the url. Not sure whether you folks had such experience. I am not sure if this is a bug in Gigya

Comment: onFieldChange only applies to the content inside a field, not a click event. I am not sure what you are using that for. You need to use your own event handler to turn turn the visibility of the text on and off.

Comment: Are you able to see the same result by using the URL? I am not sure whether this is a bug in Gigya or basically Gigya does NOT allow this kind of 'operation'. But I do not see Gigya mention in any doc or readme. Weird.

Comment: No, I can't reproduce. Screen-Sets are always loaded on the local website, only the code is hosted in the UI Builder, whenever a site loads the the Gigya Web SDK, the screen-sets are added to the page on the site that loaded the API key, so, if you are seeing different results between the UI Builder Preview mode and the live site, it has to be an issue with resources or possibly the firewall of whereever you are trying to view the site from.

Comment: Mmm, interesting to know you can see the 'eye' and it works in your live site. I opened a ticket in Gigya and the tech support see the same issue as I did. It has been escalated to their engineering team. I'm waiting for their conclusion.

Comment: The correct implementation is to change - "gigyaLoginPasswordField = document.getElementsByName('password')[0];" to "var gigyaLoginPasswordField = document.querySelector('#' + event.currentScreen + " input[name=password]");".

Comment: If I want to use check box as shown [enter image description here](see in the question description) instead of 'eye', how does Gigya handle this?

Comment: If the checkbox will be 'unchecked' every time the user opens the screen, you can do it the same way you do the eye.You wouldn't have to create an element inside the PW to contain the 'eye',but the code to actually switch the field back and forth would be essentially the same. If you are wanting to remember the user's choice,it is not supported, as even if you map a field inside the user's profile to remember the state, you can not access the field until 'after' they logged in. I guess you could set a cookie or something.But you need to account for other users using the device it may impact.

Comment: Thanks Levi! Do you mind take a look at this "in Gigya, Unable to set attribute in “email” of Screen “Forget Password” in Screen-sets ID “Default-LinkAccounts”" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47875538/in-gigya-unable-to-set-attribute-in-email-of-screen-forget-password-in-scre. Any idea on this. Thanks

Comment: Even though the solution mentioned above works fine, the potential problem comes - in a mobile phone APP, if user set the setting predictive to on, then if user chooses to show password then click submit, the password is stored somewhere and the password will show up as text  as field dropdown or show as hint above virtual keyboard when next time user click on the password field and the show password is chosen, this causes security risk for the user. Any thought on this and any solution?

Comment: @cnm Unfortunately, not that I am aware of. That is a caveat with allowing the password field to be visible and why we do not support this behavior out-of-the-box.

Comment: I asked Gigya tech support and it seems they have no clue. Not sure whether anyone out there encounter such issue and resolved it.