# in Gigya, Unable to set attribute in "email" of Screen "Forget Password" in Screen-sets ID "Default-LinkAccounts"

Tags: gigya

I have the following js implemented in Gigya JavaScript Parameters:

onAfterScreenLoad: function(event) {

```
    if ((ell = document.querySelector("#gigya-forgot-password-screen input[type=text][name=loginID]")) != null){
        ell.setAttribute('type', 'email');
        ell.setAttribute('placeholder', 'user@example.com'); 
        ell.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'); 
    }
},
```

I am able to use the above code to handle the fields of all other screen-sets EXCEPT this "Forget Password" screen (i.e. Screen ID: gigya-forgot-password-screen) in Screen-sets ID "Default-LinkAccounts".
It looks like the forgot password flow is triggered without a user session and independently of the information passed into the Email field on the login screen.
If it is, then how to implement this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the name of the field is different depending upon which screen you are using:

```
window.ell = document.querySelector("#gigya-register-screen input[type=text][name=email]");

window.ell = document.querySelector("#gigya-login-screen input[type=text][name=username]");

window.ell = document.querySelector("#gigya-forgot-password-screen input[type=text][name=username]");
```

so:

```
onAfterScreenLoad: function(event) {
    var ell = null;
    if ((event.currentScreen === "gigya-forgot-password-screen") || (event.currentScreen === "gigya-login-screen")) {
        ell = document.querySelector("#" + event.currentScreen + " input[type=text][name=username]");
    } else if (event.currentScreen === "gigya-register-screen") {
        ell = document.querySelector("#gigya-register-screen input[type=text][name=email]");
    }
    if (ell != null){       
        ell.setAttribute('type', 'email');
        ell.setAttribute('placeholder', 'user@example.com'); 
        ell.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off'); 
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and this helped.

```
if (loginScreenset !== null) {
    const input = loginScreenset.querySelector('input[name="username"]');

    if (input) {
        input.focus(); // sets focus to element
    }
}
if (regScreenset !== null){    
    const emailAddress = document.querySelector("#gigya-register-screen input[type=text][name=email]");
    if(emailAddress  !==null)
    {
        emailAddress.setAttribute('type', 'email');
        emailAddress.setAttribute('value', 'xxxxxxxx@gmail.com'); 
        emailAddress.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
    }

    const uniqueCode = document.querySelector("#gigya-register-screen input[type=number][name='data.master.unqiueCode']"); 
    if(uniqueCode  !==null)
    {
        uniqueCode.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
        uniqueCode.setAttribute('value', '12345'); 
    }
}
```